# AGM Batteries: Comparison of Auto to Marine

Tags: batteries, battery-charging

Research (links go through to the actual product descriptions, for those who read specs):

- [Diehard AGM Auto Group 34 775 CCA: **$153**](http://www.sears.com/diehard-advanced-gold-agm-battery-group-size-34/p-02850734000P?prdNo=1)
- [Diehard AGM "Marine" Group 34 880 CCA: **$250**](http://www.sears.com/diehard-platinum-marine-battery-group-size-34m-price/p-02850134000P?prdNo=2&blockNo=2&blockType=G2)
- [West Marine house brand "Dual Purpose" Group 31 **$310**](http://www.westmarine.com/buy/--dual-purpose-agm-batteries--P015020290)
- [Mastervolt (via West Marine) Group 31: **$320**](http://www.westmarine.com/buy/--12v-agm-batteries--P010976363)

Assume (I know hazards therein) a generic recreational boat setup of starter bank and house bank. I'm thinking the "auto" AGM battery is fine for both banks. Agree?

**Marinizing**: It's a sealed system afterall. I don't see what *marinizing* would bring to a AGM battery, except a higher price. Or am I offbase, and there is a *significant* (commensurate with the price jump) difference between an auto AGM and a marine AGM?

**Deep Cycle**: What is this *Dual Purpose* label on the West Marine house brand? Wouldn't any AGM battery be good for both starting and house bank? I thought the *deep cycle* battery distinction was for lead-acid batteries and was irrelevant with AGM. True?

**UPDATE** I asked this Q in another forum, and got this very helpful reply:

> The only real difference between marine & auto is primarily the terminal. Threaded studs with lock nuts are routinely used in group 24-group 31 batteries. 4D, 8D & other commercial batteries tend to have posts and other custom terminals specific to the application. Autos tend to use the posts. The "Dual Purpose" label would be used to identify a battery that is not a true deep cycle, nor is it a high calcium content cranking battery. An AGM lends itself very well to being a true dual purpose as it has significantly higher cranking amps then a gel cell (in the same size or class). In addition you will get reserve capacity that is closer to a traditional wet cell deep cycle of the same size.

Comment: I wasn't sure about this, so I looked around a bit. I can't find any conclusive evidence that it isn't just a marketing difference (auto vs marine). Check out this [ehow article](http://www.ehow.com/about_5584809_auto-vs_-marine-batteries.html).

Comment: Could the "Marine" have something to do with the form factor and terminal arrangement?

Comment: Dejvid...you are correct. See my update.